# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interferometer_seidel'

Tags: python

in the parent directory ( .. opticspy)  the module interferometer_seidel is included , when i try to import it in in python console an error appeared 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interferometer_seidel'

it would be greatfull if someone accounted such problem and knows how to solve it

Comment: There are not enough details. Think of what might be related to your question. I bet directory structure is important here.

Comment: so by import " import opticspy.interferometer_seidel"  an error appeared import opticspy.interferometer_seidel
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-ceed28f5a5c0>", line 1, in <module>
    import opticspy.interferometer_seidel

  File "C:\Users\banyo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opticspy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import aperture, interferometer_seidel,interferometer_zenike

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'interferometer_seidel'

Comment: the _init-.py looks like """
from __future__ import division as __division__
import aperture, interferometer_seidel,interferometer_zenike
import seidel, seidel2, zernike, test, tools, diffraction, jones, gauss
import phaseunwrap, lens, asphere, mplot3d, zernike_rec
import warnings as __warnings__
__warnings__.filterwarnings("ignore")